# Kivy on Android string contatenation problem with Greek characters

Tags: python, android, unicode, kivy

I have an app on Kivy for Android. I have a problem when I am trying to concatenate a string with Greek characters.

I am getting a text from a textinput in this way:

```
  ypoxreos = filter_screen.ids['ypoxreos_id'].text
```

and I want to make a concatenation to display it:

```
  filterdescr = "ΥΠΟΧΡΕΟΣ :" + ypoxreos
```

When I run this on Android, the program crashes.

On Windows it works fine.

I guess the problem is the string `ΥΠΟΧΡΕΟΣ :` in Greek.

How can I make this concatenation work in Android?

Comment: What is the exact error? Do you log it somewhere? You are sure that this is the problem? Unicode works OK in Android. It shouldn't be a problem. Did you try `"ΥΠΟΧΡΕΟΣ :{}".format(ypoxreos)` too?

Comment: Hi. "ΥΠΟΧΡΕΟΣ :{}".format(ypoxreos) didn't work. I am sure that this is the problem because when I change "ΥΠΟΧΡΕΟΣ " to "YPOXREOS" it works fine. I use `adb logcat` but I can't find the error there

Comment: The error I get with adb logcat is : `UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-1: ordinal not in range(128)`

Comment: Is it Python 3? If its 2.7, maybe you need `u"ΥΠΟΧΡΕΟΣ :"`? Do you use `future`?

Comment: It is Pyhton3. The buildozer.spec has theese requirements `requirements = kivy,sqlite3,python2,requests,plyer,pygame`. I tried `u"ΥΠΟΧΡΕΟΣ :"` , it works as concatenation but I see chinnese for the word `"ΥΠΟΧΡΕΟΣ :"`. I didn' tried `future`.

Comment: Is the encoding of your .py "utf-8"? Try to put `# coding=utf-8` as the *first* line of your script..

Comment: # coding=utf-8 as the first line of script didn't work